# How to mask logs from karate-config.js in Karate?

Tags: karate

in karate-config.js I want to log the configuration via `karate.log(config)`.

First, it looks like the config gets printed per each scenario, which is a bit unexpected. I would have expected a single print for the entire run.

Second, it seems no masking rules are applied, at least not for the junit html report. I tried different logback patterns with `%replace` as well as java `HttpLogModifier`. Both logback and `HttpLogModifier` work for STDOUT and File, but the `karate.log` statement goes unmasked into the html report.

Is there a way to fix that really all prints are masked, regardless of where they come from and where they end up?

Comment: karate-config.js runs for every scenario, that is what a test-framework typically does (clean setup and teardown). if that is a problem, you are welcome to improve karate or choose another framework. I think using a `@report=false` on the `Scenario` may work, but if not - feel free to follow this process and submit a feature request: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just to double-check, it is not intended that the logback pattern gets applied to the html report when the log comes from karate-config.js, while it gets applied for STDOUT and File?

Comment: I honestly don't know, it needs research

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#log-masking You can use java code to mask the specific info based on the header/URL. Refer above link for example.

https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/699 This should be useful as well.
You can tweak your logback.xml file as well by changing the log level or completely disabling it. Above issue has info around that.

Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: not helpful, as I have written in my question, I already have logback configured, as well as HttpLogModifier (java), and my ask is not about requests/responses but about logs from karate-config.js